# Does these sentences make sense for an English mind?

Tags: meaning

> You've got a problem - either you solve it or not. Draw is impossible.

This is my sentence. I used it when describing a mathematician and mathematics in general. The figurative meaning is that you fight a mathematical problem in a game. You either win (solve it) or lose (can't solve it). There is no third outcome.

A native speaker said that these particular sentences don't make sense. I was left wondering what might cause problems? 'Draw' means 'tie' in a sport, when neither side has won.

**EDIT**:

I can rephrase it only this way:

> You've got a puzzle, and you either solve it or not. A tie is impossible.

Comment: Out of context, I don't know what your "draw" means. Perhaps that's why they couldn't make sense of it. Another thing is perhaps in math, you need to have a problem before you start to solve it.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: 'draw' like in football or many other sports. I said that you've got the problem first.

Comment: Out of context, also "problem" is problematic. A mathematician "having a problem" means he has a puzzle to solve. "Normal" people, when they have a problem, they are in trouble. When I first read your sentence, I thought you were telling someone to get their act together :) .

Comment: Though it can be ambiguous, I think in the context, they should be able to understand you. I can understand you perfectly now.

Comment: I'm not sure who brought the problem (or the puzzle) up first. The first time I read it, I thought they brought it up and you could see through it that it's unsolvable. (I probably might say, "Your problem is unsolvable. A draw (or a tie) is impossible." It also sounds like they wanted a draw as the result.)

Comment: If it was you who brought the problem up, perhaps you could try, "This problem is interesting. It's unsolvable. A draw is impossible. As you can see, ... (then you prove it why it's unsolvable)."

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't come up with problems. The situation is general. Any mathematician faces problems.

Comment: Your own phrase is probably the best one: *You've got a new game! The game will proceed until you either win (you solved it) or lose (you couldn't solve it). There is no third outcome.*

Comment: @DamkerngT.: This phrase was intended to express that this guy hated when he could not solve a problem. If he could not solve a problem it was tantamount to losing, so there was no draw for him. ----- I've decided not to use figurative speech and simply go with the sentence "Not being able to solve a problem was devastating for him."

Comment: That's fine too! I adapted your phrase in my previous comment because I thought you're making a math game. :-)

Comment: The problem I see with the original phrasing is that solving something and drawing at something don't hang together. While keeping the game metaphor (which I like!) you could have something like "When solving a problem you can either win or lose, you can never draw."

Comment: @DamkerngT. sorry - I just noticed that my comment is very similar to yours. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of a mathematical problem many people won't see it as a game. Only in a game (such as chess) can you have a draw in the way you are using it. If you are using mathematical problems as a game them it would make sense to say "A draw is impossible."

But in your case I would prefer something like:

> You've got a problem - either you solve it completely or not at all.

You could add: "There are no points for a partially completed problem." if desired to emphasize it.

Comment: I agree but then the OP wants to emphasize it continuing the sentence and with minimum words I guess.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving using the word *problem* up to you (is it a puzzle, sum or riddle, I'm not sure!), I'll focus on what exactly you want.

I'd prefer saying this -

> You got a (puzzle/riddle/sum/problem/issue) which you can either solve it fully or drop it completely. **There is no halfway mark.**